# How to add copyright symbol in FPDF?

Tags: php, fpdf

I want to add a cell in a generated PDF with a copyright symbol .But adding the cell output shows some unwanted symbol at the beginning. Need a solution on this.

```
function Footer {
$this->SetTextColor(96,96,96);
$this->SetFont('Times','B',12);
$this->Cell(0,5,'abc Limited',0,2,'C',0);
$this->Cell(50,5,'',0,2,'C',0);
$this->Cell(0,5,'this is address',0,2,'C',0);
$this->Cell(188,5,'','B',1,'c',0);  
$this->Cell(50,5,'',0,2,'C',0); 
$this->Cell(0,5,  '©All rights reserved abc Ltd',0,1,'C',0);
}
```

Comment: To what? A file? What are you using? What have you tried? You are too unclear to answer. Have you tried UTF8 encoding?

Comment: I have edited my comment.Hope it will help you to understand

Comment: Solved it 
     

    $this->Cell(0,5,iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", "©").'reserved by abc Ltd.',0,1,'C',0);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Footer {   
    $this->Cell(0,5,iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", "©").'All rights  reserved     
Ltd.',0,1,'C',0);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I tried the "&#169" suggestion and all it showed was literally "&#169", so I tried some other options.  Just simple chr worked fine...

```
$this->Cell(0, 5, chr(169) . ' All rights reserved, etc', 0, 1, 'C', 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 choices:

1. Encode your document in utf-8 from your text Editor.
2. Use directly the Unicode Html entity &#169.This would turn your code into:

   `<?php
   $this->Cell (0'5, '&#169 All rights reserved blahblah');?>`

Comment: Using Directly Unicode HTML entity doesnt show the copyright symbol. Shows the value itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple, no need to add function footer:

```
<?php
//assume $MainPayment is a company
$MainPayment = 'Your Company';


// previous FPDF and linked library
//.. here...
$pdf->Cell(0, 8, "Copyright \xA9 $currentYear $MainPayment All rights reserved.", 0, 1, 'C');

?>
```